# Errors installing SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I'm trying to run sonarQube

Installing through cmd as Admin:
InstallNTService.bat

StartSonar.bat

```
    --> Wrapper Started as Console 
   Launching a JVM...
    Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

     2016.03.25 21:09:40 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-5.4\temp

 WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main:java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to reset file system
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to reset file system
at org.sonar.process.monitor.Monitor.resetFileSystem(Monitor.java:125)
at org.sonar.process.monitor.Monitor.startProcesses(Monitor.java:105)
at org.sonar.process.monitor.Monitor.start(Monitor.java:99)
at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:51)
at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:110)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\sonarqube-5.4\temp\jffi837955644087697080.tmp
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
at org.sonar.process.FileUtils$CleanDirectoryFileVisitor.visitFile(FileUtils.java:151)
at org.sonar.process.FileUtils$CleanDirectoryFileVisitor.visitFile(FileUtils.java:135)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Unknown Source)
at org.sonar.process.FileUtils.cleanDirectoryImpl(FileUtils.java:123)
at org.sonar.process.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:60)
at org.sonar.application.AppFileSystem.createOrCleanDirectory(AppFileSystem.java:116)
at org.sonar.application.AppFileSystem.reset(AppFileSystem.java:73)
at org.sonar.process.monitor.Monitor.resetFileSystem(Monitor.java:122)
... 10 more
 <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I' getting these errors:

1. WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main:java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to reset file system
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to reset file system
2. Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\sonarqube-5.4\temp\jffi837955644087697080.tmp

Please Assist.

Answer (score 12):

Kill the Java process and try deleting the temp folder contents again.  Worked for me.

Comment: Tried doing this, deleted temp folder, still have same problem and error message.

Answer (score 6):

The user that is running SonarQube (look at the user details in the windows services screen) must have R/W rights on several sub-directories in C:\Sonarqube-6.X. We assigned R/W rights to the whole C:\Sonarqube-6.X directory tree. Before retrying you can delete the temp directory safely. It is also essential that you unblocked the SonarQube zip-file after download and before unzipping.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but was unable to delete the temp directory because it was locked.  I restarted my computer and fired up sonarQube and it started without a problem.  I'm guessing when I last closed my SonarQube session some resource was still holding onto the temp folder and wouldn't release but I couldn't find a sonarqube process to kill off in the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps...Its work form me.

1: Stop the running sonar cmd window.

2: open Task manager and kill "Java Process" then manually delete temp folder.

3: Run Again

Thanks
Vinod

Answer (score 0):

i aslo got the same problem
use the command
source ~/.bash_profile (2times)
then go and execute sonarqn

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).